Use simulated rain in a busy scene without slowing down the system
I want to use an add-on called dynamic rain that simulates rain with particles. But these particles make the scene very heavy. Until the cpu was used up to 95% and the system was very slow and even stopped. I'm looking for a way to use this rain in a large, crowded scene full of objects, but without slowing down the system. please guide me. Thanks.

Firstly, it's a third party add-on which usually makes this question off-topic on this site. And since we do not know how this add-on exactly works it would be best to ask the developers for performance optimizations. However, since it uses the regular particle system, I guess there are only a few possible options to make the scene lighter. Surely you already baked the simulation so at least Blender does not have to calculate it new every time. The other things are reducing the number of vertices/faces on the rain drop object used for rendering and/or reducing the particle number in general.
